# Is there any communication between families of Kamsa and the Pandavas or they ever talk about each-other?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas

The following is the [first paragraph](https://www.mea.gov.in/Images/attach/amb/Volume_04.pdf#page=353) about Krishna in **THE RIDDLE OF RAMA AND
KRISHNA** by Babasaheb Dr. B.R. Ambedkar

> Now about Krishna. He is the hero of the Mahabharata. Really speaking the Mahabharata is
> principally connected with the Kauravas and the Pandavas. It is the
> story of the war fought by the two for right to the kingdom which
> belonged to their ancestors. They should be the principal characters.
> But they are not. It is Krishna who is the hero of the epic. This is a
> little strange thing. But what is stranger still is the possibility
> not being a contemporary of the Kauravas and Pandavas. Krishna was the
> friend of the Pandavas who had their empire. Krishna was the enemy of
> Kansa who also had his empire. It does not seem possible that two such
> empires should subsist side by side at once and at the same time.
> **Secondly, in the Mahabharata there is nothing to show that there was
> any intercourse between the two empires.** The two stories of Krishna
> and the Pandavas have been mixed together at some later date in order
> to provide Krishna with a larger theater to play a bigger part. The
> mixture of the two stories is the result of a deliberate design on the
> part of Vyas to glorify Krishna and to raise him above all.

The bolded sentence claims that there is no communication between the empire of Kansa and the empire of Pandavas.

Are there any statements either from the Mahabharatha or from other scriptures that show some form of communication between the two Empires?  If not, did Kamsa's family ever talk about the Pandava's family or vice-versa?

Comment: kunti was the father's sister of Shree Krishna, in that sense  Shree krishna and pandava  were brothers

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow brother-in-law right?

Comment: In north they are brothers only. Also regarding the relation did you already kewn it? or you were looking for this type only